How to add the angular component Inside GrapesJS Block
WebBuilderComponent
export class WebBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('editor', { static: true }) editorRef!: ElementRef;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      const editor = grapesjs.init({
        container: '#gjs',
        fromElement: true,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        storageManager: { autoload: false },
        plugins: ['gjs-custom-code', 'gjs-plugin-ckeditor'],
        blockManager: {
          appendTo: '#blocks',
          blocks: [
            {
              id: 'empty-mobile-container',
              label: '<b>Empty Mobile Container</b>',
              attributes: { class: 'gjs-block-mobile-container' },
              content: `<section><app-text></app-text></section>`,
              category: 'Mobile Blocks',
            },            
            {
              id: 'section', // id is mandatory
              label: '<b>Section</b>', // You can use HTML/SVG inside labels
              attributes: { class:'gjs-block-section' },
              content: `<section>
                <h1>This is a simple title</h1>
                <div>This is just a Lorem text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
              </section>`,
              category: 'Mobile Blocks',
            },
            {
              id: 'text',
              label: 'Text',
              content: '<div data-gjs-type="text">Insert your text here</div>',
            }, {
              id: 'image',
              label: 'Image',
              // Select the component once it's dropped
              select: true,
              // You can pass components as a JSON instead of a simple HTML string,
              // in this case we also use a defined component type `image`
              content: { type: 'image' },
              // This triggers `active` event on dropped components and the `image`
              // reacts by opening the AssetManager
              activate: true,
            }
          ]
        },
      });
      editor.setDevice('Mobile portrait');
    }
  }
}

Here I called component
{
 id: 'empty-mobile-container',
 label: '<b>Empty Mobile Container</b>',
 attributes: { class: 'gjs-block-mobile-container' },
 content: `<section><app-text></app-text></section>`,
 category: 'Mobile Blocks',
},

the above code is my custom component code and in that, I have used grapesJs and after that, this component was rendered on my appComponent.
now as you can see in the content I want to render my angular component but that's not working and I want to know how can I use my custom component in that.
so conclution is i want to render angular component in GrapesJs Block.
it would be grate help for me if I can achieve this functionality. Advance thanks to give your time and efforts to providing solutions.

@GiorgiosJames i would like if you address this issue and suggest me.
